# Rx Java 2 pre-pull next item on separate thread

Tags: rx-java2, backpressure

Scenario: I have a stream of data I am reading from the database. What I would like to do is read a chunk of data, process it and stream it using rx-java 2. But while I am processing and streaming it I would like to load the next chunk of data on a separate thread (pre-pull the next chunk).

I have tried:

```
Flowable.generate(...)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
  .map(...)
  .subscribe(...)
```

Unfortunately this causes the generate method to continually run on an io thread. I just want one pre-pull. I have tried using buffer, but that really just ends up creating lists of chunks.

So basically while I am streaming the current chunk on a separate thread I want to read the next chunk and have it ready.

Not sure if this is possible. I need to use generate because there is no concept of when the data will end.

I have tried using subscribe(new FlowableSubscriber(){...}) using Subscription::request but that did not seem to work.

Comment: You can add an argument to `observeOn()` that specifies the maximum buffer size that it maintains. It defaults to 128, so 128 items will be fetched at startup. If you set the value to 1, only one will be pre-fetched. Of course, your `generate()` method has to honor back pressure ...

Comment: Thanks this exactly what I needed! Thanks. By the comment "generate must honor back pressure".  Right now I am using the following flavor of generate:
Flowable.generate(emitter -> { emitter.onNext(getData();}); 
Where get data gets the chunk of data.
Is there anything specific that needs to occur in generate to honor backpressure?

Comment: `Flowable.generate()` honors backpressure by invoking your callback only as many times there is a request (from `observeOn` with 1 element fetch). You don't have to do anything in this regard.

Comment: Actually now that I am testing this, this does not seem to be working as desired. Here is what I see:
Buffer size 1: Generate->OnNext->Generate: So things are serial. Not good.
Buffer size 2: Generate(1), Generate(2)->OnNext. This is better. While OnNext is processing, generate 2 is occuring. But the problem is that the buffer doesn't replenish until it is emptied. What I want is a rolling buffer. So basically when the buffer is emptied OnNext has to wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no standard operators in RxJava that would have this type of request-response pattern. You'd need a custom `observeOn` that requests before it sends the current item to its downstream.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.reactivestreams.*;

import io.reactivex.*;
import io.reactivex.Scheduler.Worker;
import io.reactivex.internal.util.BackpressureHelper;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class LockstepObserveOnTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Flowable.generate(() -> 0, (s, e) -> {
            System.out.println("Generating " + s);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            e.onNext(s);
            return s + 1;
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .compose(new LockstepObserveOn<>(Schedulers.computation()))
        .map(v -> {
            Thread.sleep(250);
            System.out.println("Processing " + v);
            Thread.sleep(250);
            return v;
        })
        .take(50)
        .blockingSubscribe();
    }

    static final class LockstepObserveOn<T> extends Flowable<T> 
    implements FlowableTransformer<T, T> {

        final Flowable<T> source;

        final Scheduler scheduler;

        LockstepObserveOn(Scheduler scheduler) {
            this(null, scheduler);
        }

        LockstepObserveOn(Flowable<T> source, Scheduler scheduler) {
            this.source = source;
            this.scheduler = scheduler;
        }

        @Override
        protected void subscribeActual(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
            source.subscribe(new LockstepObserveOnSubscriber<>(
                subscriber, scheduler.createWorker()));
        }

        @Override
        public Publisher<T> apply(Flowable<T> upstream) {
            return new LockstepObserveOn<>(upstream, scheduler);
        }

        static final class LockstepObserveOnSubscriber<T>
        implements FlowableSubscriber<T>, Subscription, Runnable {

            final Subscriber<? super T> actual;

            final Worker worker;

            final AtomicReference<T> item;

            final AtomicLong requested;

            final AtomicInteger wip;

            Subscription upstream;

            volatile boolean cancelled;

            volatile boolean done;
            Throwable error;

            long emitted;

            LockstepObserveOnSubscriber(Subscriber<? super T> actual, Worker worker) {
                this.actual = actual;
                this.worker = worker;
                this.item = new AtomicReference<>();
                this.requested = new AtomicLong();
                this.wip = new AtomicInteger();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                upstream = s;
                actual.onSubscribe(this);
                s.request(1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(T t) {
                item.lazySet(t);
                schedule();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                error = t;
                done = true;
                schedule();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                done = true;
                schedule();
            }

            @Override
            public void request(long n) {
                BackpressureHelper.add(requested, n);
                schedule();
            }

            @Override
            public void cancel() {
                cancelled = true;
                upstream.cancel();
                worker.dispose();
                if (wip.getAndIncrement() == 0) {
                    item.lazySet(null);
                }
            }

            void schedule() {
                if (wip.getAndIncrement() == 0) {
                    worker.schedule(this);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int missed = 1;
                long e = emitted;

                for (;;) {

                    long r = requested.get();

                    while (e != r) {
                        if (cancelled) {
                            item.lazySet(null);
                            return;
                        }

                        boolean d = done;
                        T v = item.get();
                        boolean empty = v == null;

                        if (d && empty) {
                            Throwable ex = error;
                            if (ex == null) {
                                actual.onComplete();
                            } else {
                                actual.onError(ex);
                            }
                            worker.dispose();
                            return;
                        }

                        if (empty) {
                            break;
                        }

                        item.lazySet(null);

                        upstream.request(1);

                        actual.onNext(v);

                        e++;
                    }

                    if (e == r) {
                        if (cancelled) {
                            item.lazySet(null);
                            return;
                        }
                        if (done && item.get() == null) {
                            Throwable ex = error;
                            if (ex == null) {
                                actual.onComplete();
                            } else {
                                actual.onError(ex);
                            }
                            worker.dispose();
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    emitted = e;
                    missed = wip.addAndGet(-missed);
                    if (missed == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```